# Table - errors (illegal pream-token,...)

Tags: tables

Please how to repair errors in this table? Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, boldline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}


       \begin{table}[h!]
\footnotesize
\caption{Určování prvků na základě jejich charakteristického rentgenového záření}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{?C{0.8cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1.6cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{0.8cm}|C{1cm}?}


    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \multicolumn{1}{V{4}C{0.8cm}V{2.5}}{Vzorek} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{0.9cm}V{2.5}}{\centering $t$ [s] } & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1cm}V{2.5}}{\centering $\mathit{PEAK}$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1.2cm}V{2.5}}{$\mathit{FWHM}$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1.6cm}V{2.5}}{$\mathit{NET}$ $\mathit{AREA}$} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1cm}V{2.5}}{\centering $\mathit{N. A. R.}$ [cps]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1cm}V{2.5}}{\centering \%$\mathit{ERR}$ [cps]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1.5cm}V{2.5}}{\centering Prvek} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{0.8cm}V{2.5}}{\centering Přech.} &  \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1cm}V{4}}{$E_{\rm{pre}}$ [keV]}\\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

\multirow{6}{*}{1}& \multirow{6}{*}{391,36}&    \multirow{6}{*}{8,23}&  \multirow{6}{*}{1,54}&  \multirow{6}{*}{$13138 \pm 184$}&   \multirow{6}{*}{42,90}& \multirow{6}{*}{1,4}&   \multirow{6}{*}{$^{29}$Cu}& kraj&   8,979\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $1& 8,904\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $2& 8,976\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $3& 8,904\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\alpha $1&    8,046\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\alpha $2&    8,026\\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
\multirow{6}{*}{2}& \multirow{6}{*}{391,64}&    \multirow{4}{*}{28,58}& \multirow{4}{*}{1,43}&  \multirow{4}{*}{$6649 \pm 210$}&    \multirow{4}{*}{27,46}& \multirow{6}{*}{1,16}&  \multirow{6}{*}{$^{50}$Sn}& kraj&   29,200\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $1& 28,481\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $2& 29,104\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $3& 28,439\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{2}{*}{25,25}& \multirow{2}{*}{1,37}&  \multirow{2}{*}{$29684 \pm 343$ }&  \multirow{2}{*}{101,23}&    &   &   K$\alpha $1&    25,267\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\alpha $2&    25,04\\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
\multirow{6}{*}{3}& \multirow{6}{*}{391,46}&    \multirow{2}{*}{20,22}& \multirow{2}{*}{1,25}&  \multirow{2}{*}{$17689 \pm 310$}&   \multirow{2}{*}{72,61}& \multirow{6}{*}{1,75}&  \multirow{6}{*}{$^{45}$Rh}& K$\alpha $1&    20,213\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\alpha $2&    20,070\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{4}{*}{22,80}& \multirow{4}{*}{1,08}&  \multirow{4}{*}{$2799 \pm 176$}&    \multirow{4}{*}{19,24}& &   &   K$\beta $1& 22,720\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $2& 23,169\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $3& 22,695\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   kraj&   23,224\\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
\multirow{6}{*}{6}& \multirow{6}{*}{392,12}&    \multirow{2}{*}{15,80}& \multirow{2}{*}{1,19}&  \multirow{2}{*}{$14398 \pm 344$}&   \multirow{2}{*}{73,92}& \multirow{6}{*}{2,39}&  \multirow{6}{*}{$^{40}$Zr}& K$\alpha $1&    15,772\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\alpha $2&    15,688\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{4}{*}{17,94}& \multirow{4}{*}{0,26}&  \multirow{4}{*}{$640 \pm 187$}& \multirow{4}{*}{20,51}& &   &   K$\beta $1& 17,665\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $2& 17,967\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $3& 17,651\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   kraj&   17,998\\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
\multirow{5}{*}{4}& \multirow{5}{*}{486,7}& \multirow{2}{*}{10,57}& \multirow{2}{*}{1,15}&  \multirow{2}{*}{$6598 \pm 293$}&    \multirow{2}{*}{32,47}& \multirow{5}{*}{4,44}&  \multirow{5}{*}{$^{77}$Pb}& L$\alpha$1& 10,550\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   L$\alpha$2& 10,448\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{3}{*}{12,74}& \multirow{3}{*}{0,97}&  \multirow{3}{*}{$3857 \pm 229$}&    \multirow{3}{*}{27,30}& &   &   L$\beta$1&  12,612\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   L$\beta$2&  12,621\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   L$\beta$2&  12,791\\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
\multirow{6}{*}{11}&    \multirow{6}{*}{420,52}&    \multirow{2}{*}{23,18}& \multirow{2}{*}{1,32}&  \multirow{2}{*}{$31332 \pm 380$}&   \multirow{2}{*}{106,91}&    \multirow{6}{*}{1,21}&  \multirow{6}{*}{$^{48}$Cd}& K$\alpha $1&    23,170\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\alpha $2&    22,980\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{4}{*}{26,24}& \multirow{4}{*}{1,22}&  \multirow{4}{*}{$8108 \pm 234$}&    \multirow{4}{*}{32,64}& &   &   kraj&   26,711\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $1& 26,091\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $2& 26,639\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $3& 26,057\\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
\multirow{11}{*}{13}&   \multirow{11}{*}{1573,08}&  \multirow{2}{*}{10,54}& \multirow{2}{*}{1,01}&  \multirow{2}{*}{$13512 \pm 428$}&   \multirow{2}{*}{23,32}& \multirow{10}{*}{0,82}& \multirow{10}{*}{$^{77}$Pb,$^{50}$Sn}&  L$\alpha$1& 10,550\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   L$\alpha$2& 10,448\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{3}{*}{12,81}& \multirow{3}{*}{1,55}&  \multirow{3}{*}{$14265 \pm 464$}&   \multirow{3}{*}{27,39}& &   &   L$\beta$1&  12,612\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   L$\beta$2&  12,621\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   L$\beta$2&  12,791\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{2}{*}{25,24}& \multirow{2}{*}{1,46}&  \multirow{2}{*}{$56756 \pm 467$}&   \multirow{2}{*}{43,10}& &   &   K$\alpha $1&    25,267\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\alpha $2&    25,040\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{4}{*}{28,62}& \multirow{4}{*}{1,33}&  \multirow{4}{*}{$9802 \pm 275$}&    \multirow{4}{*}{11,59}& &   &   kraj&   29,200\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $1& 28,481\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $2& 29,104\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $3& 28,439\\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
\multirow{6}{*}{9}& \multirow{6}{*}{311,00}&    \multirow{2}{*}{17,46}& \multirow{2}{*}{1,30}&  \multirow{2}{*}{$18650 \pm 323$}&   \multirow{2}{*}{93,80}& \multirow{6}{*}{1,73}&  \multirow{6}{*}{$^{42}$Mo}& K$\alpha $1&    17,476\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\alpha $2&    17,371\\
\cline{3-6} \cline{9-10}
&   &   \multirow{4}{*}{19,84}& \multirow{4}{*}{0,76}&  \multirow{4}{*}{$1675 \pm 161 $}&   \multirow{4}{*}{21,11}& &   &   K$\beta $1& 19,605\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $2& 19,962\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   K$\beta $3& 19,587\\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   kraj&   20,002\\



\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

    \end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three errors:

1. Line 24 where you define the new column type `C` to take a single argument. However, in the column specification for the `tabular`, you use

   ```
   \begin{tabular}{V{4}C{0.8cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{1.1cm}|C{1.2cm}|C{1.6cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.3cm}|CV{4}{1.5cm}|}
   ```

   Note that the two last columns have a incorrect use of the new `C` column. You're probably after `...V{4}C{1.5cm}...`.
2. Line 61 has `6598 \pm 293` not in math mode. Use `$6598 \pm 293$`.
3. Line 63 has `3857 \pm 229` not in math mode. Use `$3857 \pm 229$`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Please, how can I give the content of cells in columns 7 and 8 to the center of the cell? I editted the code in question.

Comment: @Elisabeth: In order to vertically center the contents of the 7th and 8th column, use `\multicolumn{x}`with `x` being the same number that is used for the multirow commands in the corresponding row of the first and second column. Example: For the last entry, you used `\multirow{6}{*}{9}& \multirow{6}{*}{311}` in the first and second row, so `\multirow{6}{*}{1,73}&  \multirow{6}{*}{$^{42}$Mo}` will vertically center the corresponding entries in the 7th and 8th colmn as well

Comment: And horizontal center please? It should be set here?  `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`

Comment: I don't know, why this command doesn't work.

Comment: @Elisabeth: `\newcolumntype` in the way you defined it will centre the contents of a *cell* both vertically and horizontally. However, since you want to centre content across a number of cells, you need to use `\multirow`. Note though that your first row (7th column) centres content using `\multirow{6}`, while later (in the same column) you use `\multirow{4}` and then \multirow{2}`. These latter ones should change to cover the number of rows it should be spread over.

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice this mistakes are in more cells.